# Would color tags inspired from HTML be a useful feature?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Many stack exchange sites have custom markdown language specified for their site.

It is often the case that it would useful on the German stack exchange to have both English and German words colored differently using mark-down language (the color-coding would be done manually of course, not automatically.

It might be useful to color-code the words differently.

```
Was ist das deutsche Wort für mathematisches <teal>Spektrum<\teal>?

Beispielsweise gibt es ein <teal>Spektrum<\teal> von Schwarz bis Weiß mit vielen Grautönen in der Mitte.

Gibt es auch ein <teal>Spektrum<\teal> von (-∞) bis (+∞) mit der Zahl Null dazwischen?
```

We need not support all HTML colors, but we could support all colors if you want to.

Note that this is markdown language, not HTML, but the syntax for color-coded text could be similar to HTML color tags.

[image: concept art for what a question would look like if asked in different colors]

Answer (score 2):

I agree, that there seems to be a certain demand for another type of highlighting as can be easily noted by checking how ofter `code` markup is used in absence of any code.

I don't see, that colors help a lot here for these reasons:

- color names beyond the basic ones (e. g. used "teal") are not that well-known among non-native speakers.
- in your example double quotes, italics or bold face would have fulfilled the same purpose without any extension.
- visually impaired persons might be even more challenged
- I don't see, that fine-granular color definition has benefit (why use **that** color instead of say red?)
- Without substantial guidelines (who would read those?) the overall impression of a SE page may become similarly toy-like as the early webpages, including additional workload for editors and mods.
- The percentage of *advanced formatting* found in typical contributions is **very** low.

Comment: *there seems to be a certain demand for another type of highlighting as can be easily noted by checking how ofter `code` markup is used in absence of any code.* – I think the main reason for this is that people are not aware of the downsides or don’t know how to use other forms of typographical emphasis.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I wouldn't look at the name of the markdown type to derive its mandatory reason (code), but look at its effects, whih makes the code tag very suitable for song lyrics and poems, where you heed fixed line breaks. For dialogs with short sentencees it is useful too for similar reasons.

Comment: @userunknown: If you want fixed line breaks, you can force them with two spaces at the end of a line. Dialogue formatting may be only achievable through this, but we hardly ever need that. On the other hand, using code formatting for non-code breaks all sorts of things that assume it’s actual code, like screen readers, searches, etc. Also, it’s butt-ugly.

Comment: How does code formatting interfere with screen readers? How does it affect searches? What is experienced as ugly differs from user to user.

Comment: @userunknown: For example, certain characters such as `'` have different relevance in code and thus `it's` should be read differently than “it’s”. Searches may explicitly exclude code or include code. As for ugliness, yes, it is somewhat subjective, but the profession of typography exists for a reason and has long realised that cluttering the text with different backgrounds is not a good idea. Also, [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4722/42471) is an intensive discussion on this on ELU.

Comment: Can you name a search, which exclude code in code tags from searches?